# SqlPackage.exe: How can I publish N'yyyy-MM-dd' datetime value?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, dacpac

I am supposed to run `sqlpackage.exe /Action:Publish` on a `dacpac` file in order to import a database to my local development machine.

However, the import fails on datetime values that seem to be formatted like this: `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`:

> [image]
> Error: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

What do I need to do to be able to import the database into my local SQL Server installation?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You seem to have `set dateformat dmy` in effect. Have you tried `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss` format yet? The key is the `T`, making it independent of the current connection's dateformat setting.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: Very interesting. But I cannot set this session setting when I'm running `sqlpackage.exe` – can I?